# .htaccess code to block all direct access but allow internal access via include / cron_jobs / ajax requests

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm having a below folder structure(for a better understanding)

```
app
  modules
    -.htaccess
    -login.php
    -contact.php
    -email.php
  cron_jobs
    -.htaccess
    -.autoBackupDB.php
    -.autoflushTmpDirectory.php
  tmp
    -.htaccess
    <some tmp files and folders created>
```

Below is the .htaccess code that i'm using

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

What i'm trying to achieve?

I want to block all the request to these folders via direct URL, or direct call from some other way, which i'm able to do with the above `.htaccess` code but the problem arises when i'm executing cron jobs or making ajax requests. I only want the contents of the folders to be accessed by internal requests like `cron_jobs`, `request made by ajax` or `include("")` rest any kind of access to the file should be blocked.

It pops an error of `403 / 404` sometimes, which makes it not accessible.

Anyone can help me by knowing that where i'm going wrong or guide me with an updated solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 variants of cron jobs: Accessing by command line and by http/https request. This first one is not affected by web server settings. The second one can be allowed by changing the rules:

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from IP_OF_CRON_SERVER
Deny from all
```

Accessing by `include` or `require`is not affected at all.

Ajax calls are http/https requests. So there is not difference. The usual way is to allow it by server config (.htaccess) and check the rights by PHP.

Comment: what if i want to disable access to the contents of the folder via direct url access but access it via ajax call, let's say that there are some css, js, image files in assets folder, i want to deny access to entire folder content but make them accessible if called by the html file via `link` and `script` or `img src`

Comment: On server side you can't distinguish between direct url and ajax. You can only distinguish it if URL, parameters or cookies (session id) differ. And a session id together with an token can be used to distinguish between permitted and forbidden. An alternative is, that ajax uses another URL, but this can be ffaked too.

Comment: what if i'm using `deny from all` but i want to let access `scbscribe.php` and some other files in that folder

Comment: Use `<files>...</files>` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#files and create a new question on problems.

Comment: `Order`, `Allow` and `Deny` are Apache 2.2 directives and officially deprecated on Apache 2.4 (which is more likely the version you are using). If on Apache 2.4, you should be using the corresponding `Require` directive(s).